# "In such case" and "in such a case"

Tags: phrases

Could you please explain to me the difference in meaning and usage of  `in such case`  vs.  `in such a case` ?

Comment: _In such case_ is not grammatical English; if it occurs, it is a mishearing of _in such a case_. _Case_ is a count noun and needs an indefinite article in this fixed phrase.

Comment: Yes, you've got two options: *in such a case* or *in such cases*.

Comment: @JohnLawler I used to think this for quite a while - until I started hanging around with philosophers and scientists. It is standard in a lot of technical writing. I could post up several thousand instances from scholarly journals printed this year alone! It is very annoying, but it *is* standard [in such case](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?start=10&q=%22in+such+case%22&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&as_ylo=2014)

Comment: I come from scientific community and my question was motivated by the fact that I encounter "in such case" all the time in my field. Thus I was curious if there is any subtlety that differentiates meanings of the two expression. But from your comments I conclude that both have the same meaning, although "in such case" is not entirely, so to say, correct.

Comment: Interesting. I don't recall encountering it, but it's been a while since I was last on a science PhD committee (the last couple were Biology -- systematics and mosses). I can imagine it from a philosopher, but then I can imagine almost anything from one philosopher or another. It feels like it may be an analogy with _in each case_ or _in such condition/in such a condition_. Effectively such users will have moved rhetoric _case_ from a count noun to a noun like _condition_, which can appear with or without the article, as needed: _in such (a) condition/case_.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- In such a case
- In such case

The former is the most common of the two expressions and is widely used. *In such case*, however, is mostly restricted to formal writing. It is very common in law, medicine and the sciences. It wouldn't be a good idea to use this in other registers, for example in fiction or letters to friends.

The meaning of the two terms is very similar, but there's one difference that I can think of. This is that *in such case* can sometimes mean *if this is the case* as in if this is the case *right now*. So a lawyer for example might say:

- It has been suggested to us that you might have retained a copy of the keys for the premises. In such case, please return them immediately.

We can't really use *in such a case* in this instance, because *in such a case* can only really mean in cases *like* this one. It can't mean *if this is the case*.

Aside from this the two are basically freely interchangable in most of those registers where *in such case* occurs (I'll make a hedge here, in that I don't know if the legal use of the term has any special caveats).

In terms of grammar, there is also one important distinction which could account for the perseverance of *in such case* in formal writing. This is that *in such case* can take a content clause as a complement. *In such a case* does not. Here are a couple of examples:

- Even in such case that the user would have copied
  the Client Program, the use thereof would be impossible without the connection keys
  generated by the Connection Manager.

[MP Nieminen, K Kalpio, J Rinkinen - US Patent 6,578,075, 2003 ]

- In such case that the barrier to resistance of a number of
  molecules needs to be compared, resistance selection protocols need to be developed ... .

[I Vliegen, L Delang, J Neyts - Antiviral Methods and Protocols, 2013 ]

In these instances the idiom *in such case* is behaving like a conjunctive preposition (read 'subordinating conjunction').

Comment: Do you think this answer applies to the phrases "in such event" and "in such an event" as well?